# multiple pictures with coordinates C#

Tags: c#, image, picturebox

Hi im a noob in c# programing, Im trying to put  a  lot pictures 15x20 
but i want to put them in direfent coordinates example:

picture1:  Y=10 X =35

picture2  Y= 250  X =126

picture3 Y= 73 X = 97

is like 30 of them.

pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\blue.png");

any hint?
Thanks

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you mean, can you narrow it down some? Are you trying to resize images, or crop those images at the coordinates you have mentioned, or something else completely? I can't tell! Also what format of images are you working with? If you can update the question with this sort of detail it could help a lot.

Comment: Either use one control and `DrawImage()` to draw pictures on its `Graphics` on `Paint` event or dynamically create PictureBoxes. Useful information for the former option can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b818z6z6(v=vs.71).aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39219/A-Beginner-s-Primer-on-Drawing-Graphics-using-the).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to dynamicly layout picture,maybe code like the follow.

```
private void buttonLayout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x=0;
        int y=0;          
        for (int index = 0; index < 6;index++ )
        {
            string path = @"C:\Pictures\" + index.ToString() + ".png";
            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                continue;
            }
            Image image=Image.FromFile(path);
            PictureBox pictureBox = new PictureBox();
            pictureBox.Image = image;
            pictureBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            pictureBox.Left = x;
            pictureBox.Top = y;
            pictureBox.Width = image.Width;
            pictureBox.Height = image.Height;
            pictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Normal;
            panelPictures.Controls.Add(pictureBox);
            x += pictureBox.Image.Width;               
        }            
    }
```

If layout more rows,please check x and y is in the range.